# RemoteNotification From launchOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

In my application, I have added push notification service, It' all working fine.
It's require to handle notifications when App is not in active or background mode.

I added code for that as below. In method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];    
     NSDictionary *RemoteNoti =[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
     if (RemoteNoti) {
     //your methods to process notification
     }
     return YES;
}
```

eg., I got three notification
When app is not running in background or foreground and I tap on notification it gives me detail of tapped notification only.

It's giving tapped notification detail only is correct behavior? OR there should all three notification's detail of `NSDictionary *RemoteNoti =[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];`

Please suggest If I am missing anything for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes it is correct behavior.** You will be get only one notification that selected by you.

> In dictionary containing the payload of the remote notification. **> - alert:** Either a string for the alert message or a dictionary with two keys: body and **show-view. > - badge:** A number indicating the quantity of data items to download from the provider. This number is to be displayed on the app icon. The absence of a badge property indicates that any number currently badging the icon should be removed. **> - sound:** The name of a sound file in the app bundle to play as an alert sound. If “default” is specified, the default sound should be played.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So there will never a case when I get multiple notification in launch option, right?

Comment: @Nikunj - Yes .. you can not get all info of multiple notification. You are able to get only one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, At a Single Notification tap you will get only the details and info dictionary relevant to that Notification, I dont think It would be possible for you to get All the Notifications Details At Once, You may need to Store the Data as and When You receive IT , In case you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks, No I don't want to reuse it, But I was just thinking to handle it in case if I get multiple. If get single only in all case then no issue. It will work fine.